# Using LINQ ANY and occurrence > 1

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects containing a collection of child objects. I want to check if any of these objects children contain a specific value AND if they do then check if this value appears in any other objects.

I currently have this which needs to be extended for the second check:

```
public bool HasAnyTypesMoreThanOnce(IEnumerable<Parent> parents, IEnumerable<string> Types)
    {
        return parents
            .SelectMany(p => p.Children)
            .Any(c => Types.Contains(c.Type));
    }
```

I was thinking of something like this:

```
var list = parents
            .SelectMany(p => p.children)
            .Where(c => Types.Contains(c.Type))
            .Select(c => c.Type).ToList();

        return list.Count != list.Distinct().Count();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `parents.SelectMany(p => p.Children).Where(c => Types.Contains(c.Type)).Skip(1).Any();` - if we have at *least 2* children with `c.Type`

Comment: @Dmitry This doesn't guarantee we have 2 children with the **same** Type

Comment: @Ivan Stoev: if we are looking for at .least two children of the **same** type we should add `GroupBy`:  `parents.SelectMany(p => p.Children).Where(c => Types.Contains(c.Type)).GroupBy(c => c.Type).Any(chunk => chunk.Count() >= 2);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach would be to group by `Type` and return true if theres any `Type` repeating more than once otherwise false.

```
return parents.SelectMany(p => p.children)
              .Where(c => Types.Contains(c.Type))        
              .GroupBy(x => x.Type)
              .Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
parents
    .GroupBy(c => c.children.type)
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
    .Select(grp => grp.children.type);
```